# boostrap4.1: 2 overlapping columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

How to make this one in boostrap 4?

https://s8.postimg.cc/uqj2riib9/image.png

I´m using this:

```
.outer1:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 0;
top: 0;
right: -10px;
background-color: #ededed;
width: 40%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-transform: skewX(-12deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(-12deg);
transform: skewX(-12deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
-ms-transform-origin: bottom right;
transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

But it won't show after the column.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and check grammar as well as formatting of your postings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps maybe use `clip-path: polygon` tho browser support maybe limited.

Plus you will have to customise for responsive using media queries on specific column break points.

See example... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/64k27zrw/

```
.col-4 {
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.poly-1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20%;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 90% 0%, 70% 100%, 10% 100%);
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.poly-2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20%;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 90% 0%, 70% 100%, 10% 100%);
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.poly-3:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20%;
  background-color: #cd2122;
  border-radius: 5px;
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 90% 0%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%);
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```